# How to create menu of regions in Oracle Aplication Builder

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How to create menu like below
[image]
I have already craeted charts but all of them are displayed within tab open, I want to create menu like above to choose which one should be displayed.
Does anyone have suggestion or some tutorial to watch how to make these?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to to look like, but you may be interested in Region Display Selectors https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:1907:::NO:::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like a **Static content** region that has buttons as menu items. Those buttons have images on them (so that they look pretty - like the one you attached, having blue-red-green worksheets).

How to do that?

- Create a button
- modify its size using "Custom attributes" property. For example:

  ```
  style="width:100px; height:100px"
  ```
- in order to put an image onto the button, here are two options you might want to explore:

  - if it (the image) is in workspace images (uploadable as a shared component), then resize it before uploading and set it to a button by putting something like this into button's **label** property:

    ```
    <img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#PRETTY_WORKSHEETS.JPG">
    ```
  - or, use "Custom attributes" again, this time by using a fully-qualified URL as an image source, e.g.

    ```
    style="width:100px; height:100px; background-image:url('https://www.miroconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/oracle-apex-license-1.png')"
    ```

The rest should be easy, i.e. setting a link to the button so that - when pressed - it takes you to another page in this application (which is what you, probably, will do).